# How Can I optimize the query checking data from multiple rows in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically, I want to retrieve data from multiple rows in an EXT table.

```
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE 
(ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME='Charge code' and ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDATRM')
INTERSECT
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE 
(ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME='Charge code' and ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDA4RM')
INTERSECT
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE Priority > 299
INTERSECT
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE 
(ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME='Rate table rate' and ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='0.00000953')
INTERSECT
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE 
(ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME='Usage category group' and ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='H');
```

Comment: Welcome to EAV world.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @YellowBedwetter its Oracle

Comment: @lad2025 Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, it looks to like since all SELECTS are on the same table, this :

```
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE 
(ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME='Charge code' and ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDATRM')
INTERSECT
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE 
(ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME='Charge code' and ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDA4RM')
INTERSECT
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE Priority > 299
```

yields the same result as this :

```
Select package_id from EXT  WHERE 
(ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME='Charge code' and ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDATRM')
AND
(ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME='Charge code' and ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDA4RM')
AND
(Priority > 299)
```

The second approach is more readable and I suspect it would be quicker to execute as well.

Comment: The problem with the solution which u provided is , if you see my SQL it is intersecting common package_ids. But the query which u provided it will not intersect ,It will work like a Union and not intersect. Ex :- Suppose there are 3 rows present in the table and  Package_id is 1 where ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDATRM' and Package_id is also 1 for  ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDA4RM' also another row is Package_id is 2 where  ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE='WDATRM' ur query will return both the package_ids but it should return only Package_id 1

Comment: @PalashManawat I might have typed this quickly before going to lunch, I believe the solution would be functional if I used "AND" instead of "OR". That way only rows where all predicates are true (much like an intersection) will return.

Comment: no offence but if the solution of that problem would have been that simple I would have known that...the problem with AND is that it won't work on mutiple rows....I have 2 queries for that question 1 using intersection and the second is using IN....IN is very very slow and intersection is faster than IN but i feel like that Intersection one is not the optimal..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it'll be faster, but you could give a JOIN based approach a shot

```
SELECT CON1.package_id
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT package_id
          FROM EXT 
         WHERE ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Charge code' 
           AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = 'WDATRM'
       ) CON1
 INNER
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT package_id
          FROM EXT 
         WHERE ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Charge code' 
           AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = 'WDA4RM'
       ) CON2
    ON CON1.package_id = CON2.package_id
 INNER
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT package_id
          FROM EXT 
         WHERE Priority > 299
       ) CON3
    ON CON1.package_id = CON3.package_id       
 INNER
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT package_id
          FROM EXT 
         WHERE ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Rate table rate' 
           AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = '0.00000953'
       ) CON4
    ON CON1.package_id = CON4.package_id       
 INNER
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT package_id
          FROM EXT 
         WHERE ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Usage category group' 
           AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = 'H'
       ) CON5
    ON CON1.package_id = CON5.package_id
```

**EDIT:** That first one didn't work. Maybe INTERSECTS are as good as it gets. I'd be surprised if this one is better, but maybe.

```
SELECT DISTINCT package_id
  FROM (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Charge code' 
                         AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = 'WDATRM' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                  ) OVER 
                 ( PARTITION BY package_id ) CON1,
               MAX(CASE WHEN ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Charge code' 
                         AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = 'WDA4RM' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                  ) OVER 
                 ( PARTITION BY package_id ) CON2,
               MAX(CASE WHEN Priority > 299 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                  ) OVER 
                 ( PARTITION BY package_id ) CON3,
               MAX(CASE WHEN ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Rate table rate' 
                         AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = '0.00000953' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                  ) OVER 
                 ( PARTITION BY package_id ) CON4,  
               MAX(CASE WHEN ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Usage category group' 
                         AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = 'H' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                  ) OVER 
                 ( PARTITION BY package_id ) CON5,  
               CON1 + CON2 + CON3 + CON4 + CON5 AS ALLCON
          FROM EXT     
       ) TMP
 WHERE ALLCON = 5;
```

Comment: It did work and thanks for all your efforts... I will check if its performing good enough.

Comment: From the performance point of view my query is working faster and I am sorry to say that :)..

Comment: Bummer, I added an alternative but I don't expect it to be better. Do you have indexes defined on ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME or ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE?

Comment: I wrote it using IN and it is taking  from 5/6 to 7/8 of less time in execution. I think I can close this question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (package_id)
  FROM EXT
 WHERE Item_param_attr_name = 'Usage category group'
   AND Item_param_attr_value = 'H'
   AND package_id IN
       (SELECT DISTINCT (package_id)
          FROM EXT
         WHERE Item_param_attr_name = 'Charge code'
           AND Item_param_attr_value = 'WDATRM'
           AND Priority > 299
           AND package_id IN
               (SELECT DISTINCT (package_id)
                  FROM EXT
                 WHERE Item_param_attr_name = 'Charge code'
                   AND Item_param_attr_value = 'WDA4RM'
                   AND package_id IN
                       (SELECT DISTINCT (package_id)
                          FROM EXT
                         WHERE ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_NAME = 'Rate table rate'
                           AND ITEM_PARAM_ATTR_VALUE = '0.00000953')));
```